# How to Turn a Slider Output into a Variable with Javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to make a slider like the one [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jquerymobile/tryit.asp?filename=tryjqmob_forms_slider), and want to make the output a variable. The problem is, though, is that I don't know where the output is. This the code for the slider -

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div data-role="page">
  <div data-role="header">
    <h1>Slider Control</h1>
  </div>

  <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
    <form method="post" action="demoform.asp">
      <label for="points">Points:</label>
      <input type="range" name="points" id="points" value="50" min="0" max="100">
      <input type="submit" data-inline="true" value="Submit">
    </form>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Yes, I'm aware this uses jquery, by the way. Anyway, can you show me a few lines of code to add (or change) to make the output change a variable? Thanks!

Comment: You mean like this? `console.log($('#points').val());`

Comment: I want it to be a variable, not console.log

Comment: Well, just do `let points = $('#points').val();`

Answer (score 1):

You can get the value of slider on `slidestop` or `change` event

```
<script>
var sliderValue;
$(function () {
   $("#points").on("slidestop", function () {
     sliderValue =  $(this).val();
   })
   $("#points").on("change", function () {
     sliderValue =  $(this).val();
   })
});
</script>
```

You can add this just before close of `body` tag.

Comment: I want to turn the output of the slider into a variable

Comment: @NathanChan this code is putting the value of slider in `variable sliderValue`

Comment: @NathanChan: Start by reading about what is a "[variable](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_variables.asp)". Maybe you're not using the right words to describe your question.

Comment: @NathanChan you are putting your feet on step 2 with out putting on step 1.

Comment: What my ultimate goal is to make the slider bar effect what image is on a slideshow

Comment: You now have the value of the slider in a variable named `sliderValue`. You have to use it in the slideshow script.

Answer (score 0):

```
This is test to see if what you(Leopard) made worked - 

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div data-role="page">
  <div data-role="header">
    <h1>Choose the Height of Your Building</h1>
  </div>

  <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
    <form method="post" action="demoform.asp">
      <label for="percentage">Percentage:</label>
      <input type="range" name="percentage" id="percentage" value="50" min="1" max="100">
      <input type="submit" data-inline="true" value="Submit">
    </form>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
var sliderValue;
$(function () {
   $("#percentage").on("slidestop", function () {
     sliderValue =  $(this).val();
   })
   $("#percentage").on("change", function () {
     sliderValue =  $(this).val();
   })
});

<document.getElementById("print2").innerHTML = sliderValue>

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

It didn't work.